# List shifts down on item placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I'm having a hard time fixing the following issue: one of my lists, #cardHolder, moves down whenever I drag an item in it.
I know it's CSS related, but I can't seem to fix it.
Any help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#cardHolder, #hand" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      receive: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.children('li').length > 1 && $this.attr('id') != "hand") {
      console.log('Only one per list!');
      $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            }
      }

    }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#trumpHolder{
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
#holderWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

}
#cardHolder {
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#cardHolderOther{
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.table{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;


}
#hand {
    height: 250px;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

#cardHolder li, #hand li {
    margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="boerenbridge.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boerenbridge.css">


<ul id="trumpHolder" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>
<div id="holderWrapper">
<ul id="cardHolder" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>
<ul id="cardHolderOther" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>
</div>
<div class="table">
<ul id="hand" class="connectedSortable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Boerenbridge</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="boerenbridge.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boerenbridge.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul id="trumpHolder" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>
<div id="holderWrapper">
<ul id="cardHolder" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>
<ul id="cardHolderOther" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>
</div>
<div class="table">
<ul id="hand" class="connectedSortable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#trumpHolder{
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
#holderWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

}
#cardHolder {
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#cardHolderOther{
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.table{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;


}
#hand {
    height: 250px;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

#cardHolder li, #hand li {
    margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#cardHolder, #hand" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      receive: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.children('li').length > 1 && $this.attr('id') != "hand") {
      console.log('Only one per list!');
      $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            }
      }

    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks for editing, I'm having some issues with Jquery in fiddle.

Comment: What are the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `#cardHolder` when using `display: inline-block` to make sure it sticks to the top, otherwise it will try to align it to its default value, `baseline`, [see this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) for more information on `vertical-align` and `inline` elements.

Below, on the left, is an example of `vertical-align` using the default `baseline` value, on the right is an example of it using the `top` value.

```css
.inline-list {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}

.inline-list div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #444;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

.inline-list .cardholder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.inline-list.align .cardholder {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-list">
    <div class="cardholder">Some text</div>
    <div class="cardholder"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="inline-list align">
    <div class="cardholder">Some text</div>
    <div class="cardholder"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Well that solved it. Thanks a lot! I kind of feel embarrassed right now.

Comment: Haha, welcome @Lars! No need to be. It's a thing to be wary of when using `display: inline-block` I added an example which illustrates what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your css :

```css
#cardHolder {
    vertical-align : top;
    ...
```

See the working example below !

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#cardHolder, #hand" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      receive: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.children('li').length > 1 && $this.attr('id') != "hand") {
      console.log('Only one per list!');
      $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            }
      }

    }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#trumpHolder{
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
#holderWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

}
#cardHolder {

    vertical-align : top; /* <--------------- MODIFICATION */

    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#cardHolderOther{
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.table{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;


}
#hand {
    height: 250px;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

#cardHolder li, #hand li {
    margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="boerenbridge.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boerenbridge.css">


<ul id="trumpHolder" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>
<div id="holderWrapper">
<ul id="cardHolder" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>
<ul id="cardHolderOther" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>
</div>
<div class="table">
<ul id="hand" class="connectedSortable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Lars yes it take less time to write 1 line than edit and provide an working example !